# VB6 Printing to Zebra printer over network on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, printing, vb6

I inheritied the code for printing shipping labels to a Zebra s600 printer, and while the code works fine in Windows XP, I can't figure out why it doesn't work in Windows 7.

I get the following error when running the program in Windows 7:
"Run time error '75' Path/File access error"

But it runs in WindowsXP, so the path is not wrong.

EDIT: I have tried running in comparability mode along with right clicking and running the program as an admin. Still doesn't work.

```
Sub PrintLabel()
'**** this sub print a barcode label on the Zebra S600 printer
'**** for the cardboard shipping box.
Dim mySNprinter As String

mySNprinter = GetSetupVariable("TestSnPrinter")

If (mySNprinter = "") Then
    mySNprinter = "\\dc1\bertha"
End If

 Open mySNprinter For Output As #3
    Print #3, "^XA"         'start of data
    Print #3, "^LH20,25"    'home position of label is 5,25
    If optSize(0).Value = True Then
        Print #3, "^FO1,30^A0,N,25,25^FD" & cboLabel.Text & "^FS"    'print MP-1 with the D font
    End If
    If optSize(1).Value = True Then
        Print #3, "^FO1,30^A0,N,35,35^FD" & cboLabel.Text & "^FS"    'print MP-1 with the D font
    End If
    If optSize(2).Value = True Then
        Print #3, "^FO1,30^A0,N,50,50^FD" & cboLabel.Text & "^FS"    'print MP-1 with the D font
    End If
    Print #3, "^XZ"                     'end data
 Close #3
```

Comment: And at which line did you receive that error?

Comment: Did you try right-click on exe and "Run as Administrator"?

Comment: Yes, I tried running as Admin, and I'm getting the error on the first Print Line (Print #3, "^XA")

Comment: Does that share/printer name work and is it accessable from the Windows 7 machine? Just because it works on one doesn't mean it'll work on another...

Comment: Yes, when I set it to the default device in the settings it will print text on the machine. ALthough I can't send the special commands like in the code above)

Comment: I ended up creating a .net application instead using a socket. Worked out perfectly.